# Exercising and running in cold / winter

Tags: running, cold

This year is my first time running regularly, but as the autumn is approaching (and consequently winter, about which I am more concerned about), I would like to know a little more about healthy practices of workout.

First of all, my workout does not consist of only running. After running (usually about ~6 km), I come home and do about 2 x 50 push-ups, then about 2 x 40 and some stretching (about, as I am slowly increasing the amount of repetitions in series). During summer, this poses no problem, because I will eventually cool down.
(I do this 2-3 times a week)

**But in autumn / winter, what should I do?**

1. Run -> Push ups -> Shower
2. Push ups -> Run -> Shower
3. Run -> Shower (and just do the push ups other day)

In winter, the temperature can drop to about -15 Celsius, but that's extreme in my city, usually the average temperature is about -3 Celsius in January

EDIT: I usually finish my running cycle near my flat, so being exposed to cold and not running isn't an issue.

Comment: Consider incorporating a workout for your [core](http://minneapolisrunning.com/5-core-strengthening-workouts-you-might-actually-do/).

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry yourself with details such as this. Whichever order you feel like doing them in, is fine.

It's going to make no difference at all.

Comment: In [this answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/10356/23423) Arthlete says, that stabilising your temperature after running in cold is recommended, but if I take my usual course of action, do I stabilise it by exercising at home?

Comment: -3C is not that cold. Once you get moving, you might even prefer it to your normal temperature. -15C however is cold and make sure you stay dry. Damp clothing will drastically lower your body temperature.